# Listening datagram socket with any ip and any port number android

Tags: android, sockets, broadcast, datagram, socket-timeout-exception

Hi Am sending broadcast using DatagramSocket with specific port number. Its successfully send message. But when i listening for receive message with open ip address and any port number it throwing sockettimeoutexception. But am connected with the same network.

//manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

//defined port number globally

```
int PORT=2739;
```

// starting async task

```
new MyClientTask().execute();
```

///async task

```
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            new PacketSender().run();
            new PacketReceiver().run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


        }

    }
```

This is my sending request

```
public class PacketSender implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DatagramSocket sendSoc = null;
            try {
                sendSoc = new DatagramSocket();
                sendSoc.setBroadcast(true);
                sendSoc.setSoTimeout(5000);
                sendSoc.setReuseAddress(true);
                byte[] ip = prop.ToBuffer();
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(ip,
                        ip.length, getBroadcastIp(), PORT);
                Log.d("Sending", packet.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " " + packet.getPort());
                sendSoc.send(packet);
                sendSoc.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Send", "IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (sendSoc != null)
                    sendSoc.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my listening request

```
public class PacketReceiver implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DatagramSocket receiveSoc = null;
            try {
              //here 0 represent any port number including system reserved port number
                receiveSoc = new DatagramSocket(0, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));  
                receiveSoc.setBroadcast(false); //also tried with true
                receiveSoc.setSoTimeout(5000);  //alse tried with removing timeout value

                int i = 0;
                while (true) {
                    Log.d("data value", " " + i);
                    i++;
                    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
                    DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

                    try {
                        receiveSoc.receive(pack);

                        String message = new String(pack.getData()).trim();
                        Log.i("test", message + " server ip : " + pack.getAddress().getHostAddress());

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                Log.d("Main", "SocketTimeoutException");
                e.printStackTrace();
                receiveSoc.close();
                new PacketReceiver().run();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("Response", "IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

//getting broadcast ip

```
public InetAddress getBroadcastIp() throws IOException {
        DhcpInfo dhcp = myWifiManager.getDhcpInfo();
        int broadcast = (dhcp.ipAddress & dhcp.netmask) | ~dhcp.netmask;
        byte[] quads = new byte[4];
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            quads[k] = (byte) ((broadcast >> k * 8) & 0xFF);
        return InetAddress.getByAddress(quads);
    }
```

It can able to receive broadcast message from all host in LAN except the hardware which i want to communicate. I can send broadcast to it.But i cant able to receive broadcast from this particular device.

Comment: please comment me if you are not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue from the below. There is no problem with packet forwarding in network. I send and receive broadcast on the same socket object with setBroadcast value true. So socket send broadcast and listening for any broadcast from the same. You should not use different socket object for listening broadcast. I understand it very late.

```
public class PacketSender extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DatagramSocket sendSoc = null;
            try {
                sendSoc = new DatagramSocket();
                sendSoc.setBroadcast(true);
                InetSocketAddress  address = new InetSocketAddress(getBroadcastQuadIp(), PORT);

                byte[] ip = prop.ToBuffer();
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(ip,
                        ip.length, address.getAddress(), address.getPort());


                sendSoc.send(packet);    

                //////////// receiver begin
                int i = 0;
                while (true) {

                    i++;

                    final byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
                    final DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                    try {
                        sendSoc.receive(pack);

                        String message = new String(pack.getData()).trim();

                        Log.i("test", message + " server ip : " + pack.getAddress().getHostAddress());

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Send", "IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (sendSoc != null)
                    sendSoc.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes to your code:

```java
public class PacketSender implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // ...

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(ip,
                ip.length, InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"), PORT);

        // ...
    }
}
```

```java
public class PacketReceiver implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // ...

        receiveSoc = new DatagramSocket(PORT, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));

        // ...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The `MyClientTask` code doesn't work because it calls the sender and the receiver sequentially. The sender will send to no one and the receiver will wait forever for no message. You have to call the sender while the receiver is already listening to datagrams.

So, instead of

```java
new MyClientTask().execute();
```

You'll want something like

```java
new Thread(new PacketReceiver()).start();

// Just to make sure that the receiver has started up.
// You'll want to do a different kind of synchronization.
SystemClock.sleep(50);

new Thread(new PacketSender()).start();
```

Comment: thank you for response. Its not working . Even its not sending msg. Before it was fine.

Comment: thank you its not working am already did like that for SO i simplified it .It can able to receive broadcast message from all host in LAN except the hardware which i want to communicate. I can send broadcast to it.But i cant able to receive broadcast from this particular device. In LAN my ip is 192.168.0.100 the device ip which am listening is 192.168.0.101. Other than this ip i can able to receive all broadcast msg in LAN. But its not my need.

Comment: @Nas what do you mean by 'simplify'? if your simplification is the `MyClientTask` class it won't work at all as i have already stated